# How to change rel of the anchor in the page when href contains specific keywords

Tags: javascript

I have an affiliate related blog which means that Google wants all of my affiliate links to be marked as sponsored links with rel = "sponsored".

Not all of the links on my website are affiliate links so I only would like to trigger the script below when a href on the page contains specific keywords.

Let's say I have 3 types of affiliate href links.

```
abc178.com/ref=xyz   
qrs221.com/ref=xyz   
xyz952.com/ref=xyz
```

I only want this sript to run when 'abc', 'qrs' and 'xyz' is found in a href

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
if (location.hostname!=x[i].hostname){
x[i].rel = "sponsored";
x[i].target = "_blank";
x[i].title = "Click to open in new window";
}}}
mft=setTimeout("myFunction()",0);
function LoadEvent(func){
var oldonload = window.onload;
if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){
window.onload = func;
}
else{
window.onload = function()
{
if(oldonload)
{oldonload();}
func();}}}
LoadEvent(function(){
myFunction();
});
</script>
```

I'm no programmer, but I suppose this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  // make sure dom elements are rendered before sc run
  let keywords = ['abs', 'qrs', 'xyz'];
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(anchor=>{
    // iterate all anchor tags in dom
    let href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
    let flag = false;
    keywords.forEach(kw=>{
      if(href.includes(kw)){
        flag = true;
      }
    });
    if(flag){
      anchor.setAttribute('rel', 'sponsored');
      anchor.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      // anchor.innerHTML = 'Click to open in new window';
    }
  });
});
```

I totally understand how confusing those url references are: `href`, `link`, `rel`, `src`, `hostname`, `location`, especially for frontend beginners. however, those are essential conventions to adopt to build more flexible and sophisticated application.

I would say a simple way to remember,

- `href` always refer to `a` anchor tag.
- `src` indicates `image` or `script` url.
- `window.location` and `window.hostname` are the current page url.

if the script above, I am trying to iterate all `anchor` tags, check if any's `href` contains the keywords, if so, overwrite their `rel` to `sponsored` and `target` to `_blank` (if you want to change the content text, do not use title, use `innerHTML`) instead.

here are some useful resources:

- [a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)
- [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but somehow the sponsored rel is not being added.

Comment: @Justmac, my bad, I thought you meant the parameter but hostname.

Comment: does it mean it is not possible based on hostname?
I would like to add a general script to my website that changes only urls that contain 'abc', 'qrs' and 'xyz'

Comment: @Justmac I have updated the answer yesterday, have a go man, sorry I did not mention it in last comment. for the updated script, will only be executed if hostname contains those keywords.

Comment: oh I tried, but it didn't work so I thought it was still the same. 
I think it's because of a misunderstanding. 

I see the script only works when I specify the page url that the script runs on.
However, the script should always run on my page, but only apply the 'Sponsored' rel when a url link on the page contains 'abc', 'qrs', 'xyz'. 

The reason is that I only want to apply the script on affiliate links and with the 'abc', 'qrs', 'xyz' I can specify which links are affiliate links.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Justmac, man I have a bit confusion. I haven't look into your script's detail before, what I did was simply add a conditional that quit if the host name includes those keywords. In your own script, I can see you getting an anchor tag in Dom, then tries to overwrite the `rel`, so let me make it clear, **are you trying to change all anchor tag's `rel` attribute to `Sponsored` if the hostname include those keywords ?**, or **are you trying to change `rel` of the anchor in the page which href contains those keywords**, if so, please edit the question title, it is a completely different question.

Comment: sorry I now understand your confusion. I should have used the name href and not URL. I've edited the question title and also parts of the description as it should change the rel of the anchor in the page when href on the page contains specific keywords. Is this possible by modifying the script?

Comment: any ideas after my modification?

Comment: @Justmac updated 6 hours ago

Comment: Perfect and thank you for your kind asnwer!